# How to split array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerator

I am trying to split an array of hashes. All hashes have the same keys. The expected result would be something that looks like this:

```
1 = [{"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => true}]
2 = [{"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => true}]
3 = [{"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => nil}, {"tid" => true}]
```

I'm trying to get this code working:

```
buyer_ids = specific_buyer.slice_after{ |obj| obj["tid"] != nil}
# => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ffe9ea2f5b8>:each>
```

I have no clue what the result means.

Comment: Just call `.to_a` on `buyer_ids`

Answer (score 2):

It's correct. Just add a `to_a` or call a method on the resulting collection to verify that

```
buyer_ids.slice_after { |obj| obj["tid"] != nil }.to_a
buyer_ids.slice_after { |obj| obj["tid"] != nil }.each { |item| puts item }
```